MongoDB: Filter array field based on entry from the same array
Given the following collection
db.playground.insertMany([
  { "id": 1, "tags": [{"t": "T1", "v": "t11", "c": 1 }, {"t": "T2", "v": "t12"}, {"t": "T3", "v": "t13"}]},
  { "id": 2, "tags": [{"t": "T1", "v": "t21", "c": 2 }, {"t": "T2", "v": "t22"}, {"t": "T3", "v": "t23"}]},
  { "id": 3, "tags": [{"t": "T1", "v": "t22", "c": 2 }, {"t": "T2", "v": "t21"}, {"t": "T3", "v": "t33"}]},
])


How could I filter the tags array for each document so that they only contain:

The tags with t = T2 or t = T3 if there's at least one tag in the same array with t = T1, v = t21 and c = 1
The tags with t = T1 or t = T3 if there's at least one tag in the same array with t = T1, v = t21 and c = 2

This is my current attempt at it, but there are some issues with it:

I don't understand why the predicate { $eq: ["$tags.v", "t21"] } doesn't work
I don't understand why this requires square brackets { $eq: ["$tags.c", [1]]} and it doesn't work when I use NumberInt like here { $eq: ["$tags.c", NumberInt(1)] }
How can I make sure that c and v belong to the same tag? My current example also returns the 3rd entry which meets one condition on one tag and the second on the other.

db.playground.find({},
  {
    id: 1,
    tags: {
      $filter: {
        input: "$tags",
        as: "tag",
        cond: {
          $or: [
            { $and: [
                // { $eq: ["$tags.v", "t21"]}, // Why does this not work
                { $eq: ["$tags.c", [1]]}, // Why does this work as an array?
                { $in: ["$$tag.t", ["T2", "T3"]] }
              ]
            },
            { $and: [
                // { $eq: ["$tags.v", "t21"]}, // Why does this not work
                { $eq: ["$tags.c", [2]]},  // Why does this work as an array?
                { $in: ["$$tag.t", ["T1", "T3"]] }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      }
  }}
)

Playground

Your description seems rather complex and mixes a lot of things. To start with, is this what you want for the first criteria?

For your concerns on how $filter works, you seem to mix up the basis of how it works. Please read this official doc to learn how $filter iterates through the array, especially to clarify $tags refers to whole array/array level; while $$tag refers to the individual array element/sub document level.

from what i underrstand only the id:2 should return a non empty tags array

@ray Thank you, the example is enough to get me started. As for $filter, I'll have a look once more at the docs. I understand the difference between $$tag and $tags, I just didn't know how to express the condition "If the entire array contains an object matching {"t": "T1", "v": "t21", c: 1} ....".

@cmgchess That is correct, id:1 does not match because v is not t11 and id:3 does't match because v and c are on different tags.

@BobbyTables You can check the playground that I provided earlier on. The $anyElementTrue is applied on a $map, which check for the condition you mentioned. So if the array contain an element you mentioned, the $anyElementTrue will return true
